# Powershell extract after space and before special character

Tags: powershell

```
:3779:<![LOG[Resolved and downloaded package SDD344455 to **C:\Windows\ccmcache\3**]LOG]!><time="08:03:15"
```

please advise who to extract **C:\Windows\ccmcache\3** from the string, been trying regex for hours. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried and what result are you getting? Paste it into the Question body so you can be better helped.

Comment: [string]$extractS=[regex]::Matches($s, '(to)=/s+.*\]LOG') 

1st time trying regex

Comment: [string]$extractS=[regex]::Matches($s, '(?<=to )(.*)(?=]LOG)') 

got it to work finally.
is this the only way?

Comment: Best to use what works. There are a magnitude of different ways to accomplish things, but regex is typically very specific. If it works for you, stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[regex]::Matches($string,"to\s(.+)]LOG").Groups[1].Value
```